# AngularJS Вывод через groupBy

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get('http://site.com/events/5346343453')
.then(function(response) {
$scope.items = response.data;

$scope.grouppedItems = _.groupBy($scope.items, function(item) {
return $scope.toDate(item.date);
});
})
```

В ответ приходит массив:

```
{mid: "5346343453", name: "oleg", txt: "текст1", date: "03.12.2017 18:41:00"}
{mid: "5346343453", name: "oleg", txt: "текст2", date: "02.12.2017 19:08:26"}
{mid: "5346343453", name: "oleg", txt: "текст3", date: "02.12.2017 19:08:24"}
{mid: "5346343453", name: "oleg", txt: "текст4", date: "02.12.2017 19:06:19"}
{mid: "5346343453", name: "oleg", txt: "текст5", date: "02.12.2017 19:06:16"}
{mid: "5346343453", name: "oleg", txt: "текст6", date: "02.12.2017 15:43:54"}
```

Вьюшка:

```
<div class="evDivs" ng-repeat="(date, items) in grouppedItems">
<div class="bg-success"><strong>{{ date }}</strong></div>
<div ng-repeat="info in items">
{{info.name}} : {{info.txt}}
</div>
</div>
```

Только никак не пойму, почему дни выводятся не по убывания, а по возрастанию:

```
02.12.2017 
oleg: текст2
oleg: текст3
oleg: текст4
oleg: текст5
oleg: текст6
03.12.2017
oleg : текст1
```

Comment: Судя по всему, underscore.groupBy использует обычный объект javascript для группировки, а в нём порядок ключей не определён.

Comment: Пути решения в данном случае какие-то имеются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, `underscore.groupBy` использует обычный объект javascript для группировки, а в нём порядок ключей не определён.

Проще всего сгруппировать вручную с сохранением порядка появления дат в отдельном массиве:

```
$http.get('http://site.com/events/5346343453')
  .then(function(response) {
     var groupKeys = [];
     var groupData = {};
     response.data.forEach(function(item) {
       var gkey = $scope.toDate(item.date);
       if (!groupData[gkey]) {
         groupKeys.push(gkey);
         groupData[gkey] = [];
       }
       groupData[gkey].push(item);
     });

     $scope.itemGroupOrder = groupKeys;
     $scope.groupedItems = groupData;

  });
});
```

Ну и вьюшка:

```
<div class="evDivs" ng-repeat="gkey in itemGroupOrder">
  <div class="bg-success"><strong>{{ gkey }}</strong></div>
  <div ng-repeat="info in groupedItems[gkey]">
    {{info.name}} : {{info.txt}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня в консоли выводится ошибка: ReferenceError: gropData is not defined, и жалуется на строку:  if (!gropData[gkey])

Comment: Очевидно, тут опечатка, не хватает `u`. У меня под рукой ни ангуляра, ни сервера с данными, ни кучи ваших функций навроде `$scope.toDate`... только вот textarea для текста ответа.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Код актуален!